# Automating a desktop app based on Chromium Embedded Framework using Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

**Background:**
At work we are passing the --remote-debugging-port=9555 parameter to a CEF based desktop app and launching it using `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("path to app")`. Then, using selenium, we open an instance of chrome and open the link http://localhost:9555 in it. This displays the entire html code of the desktop app in that browser instance.
Then we perform interactions like button clicks and data entry on the chrome browser using selenium. Any interaction performed on the browser is reflected on the app as well.
**Query:**
On many screens of the desktop app, the html visible on chrome browser to the user is different from the html visible to selenium. We confirmed this by running `driver.getPageSource()` and observing completely different css and html. Due to this, buttons visible to the user on the screen are not visible to selenium. Hence selenium cannot click on the buttons on those screens. Is there way to solve this problem and get selenium to interact with those buttons?

Comment: getPageSource returns the original delivered HTML. AJAX and JavaScript in the page can and will alter the state of the page during loading, page actions, and the like. These changes are not seen in pageSource.

However, this should not be a problem for Selenium, as Selenium itself deals with the page structure as currently exists, and doesn't depend on pageSource. So I suggest your problem is something else, such as broken locators.

Answer (score 0):

If you query the page source using selenium you'll actually get the source and not the DOM, so anything you do dynamically to the source code via JS will not be displayed in the output. Seleniums interactions though do actually access the DOM so using the returned page source as a metric for what is "visible" to selenium is problematic at least. If you'd provide some more information on what you're actually trying to do I'd like to provide some more constructive advice.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this problem is to use the DevTools API provided by the ChromeDriver to interact with the CEF-based desktop app. This allows you to directly manipulate the DOM of the app, rather than relying on the HTML code visible in the Chrome browser.

Here's an example of how to use the DevTools API to click on a button in the CEF-based desktop app:

1 First, create a new ChromeDriver instance and connect to the app using the remote debugging port:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9555");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

2 Next, get the DevTools instance from the driver:

```
DevTools devTools = ((ChromeDriver) driver).getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();
```

3 Use the DevTools API to find the button element and click on it:

```
devTools.send("Runtime.enable", null);
devTools.send("DOM.getDocument", null);
devTools.addListener("DOM.querySelector", query -> {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("nodeId", query.get("nodeId").getAsDouble());
    params.put("selector", "button.my-button");
    devTools.send("DOM.querySelector", params);
});
devTools.addListener("DOM.querySelectorCompleted", result -> {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("nodeId", result.get("nodeId").getAsDouble());
    devTools.send("DOM.describeNode", params);
});
devTools.addListener("DOM.describeNodeCompleted", result -> {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("objectId", result.get("node").getAsJsonObject().get("objectId").getAsString());
    devTools.send("Runtime.getProperties", params);
});
devTools.addListener("Runtime.getPropertiesCompleted", result -> {
    for (JsonElement property : result.get("result").getAsJsonArray()) {
        if (property.getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString().equals("click")) {
            String objectId = property.getAsJsonObject().get("value").getAsJsonObject().get("objectId").getAsString();
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("objectId", objectId);
            devTools.send("Runtime.callFunctionOn", params);
            break;
        }
    }
});
devTools.send("DOM.querySelector", null);
```

This code uses the DevTools API to find the button element with the class name "my-button", and then calls the "click" function on it to simulate a click event. This should work even if the HTML code visible to Selenium is different from the HTML code visible in the Chrome browser.

Note that this is just an example, and you may need to modify the code to suit your specific use case. Also, keep in mind that using the DevTools API directly can be more complex and less stable than using Selenium, so use it with caution.